# Sql Query get dates exclude specific months

Tags: sql, datetime, subquery, where-clause

I need to get values for data excluding specific months by status.

T1 table

```
Date        
------------
2020-01-12    
2020-02-11    
2020-03-18
2020-03-24
2020-04-08
2020-05-20
2020-05-30
2020-06-22
2020-07-02
```

T2 Table

```
StartDate    Id   Status 
-------------------------
2020-01-01    1    Open
2020-02-01    2    Close
2020-03-01    3    Open
2020-04-01    4    Close
2020-05-01    5    Close
2020-06-01    6    Open
2020-07-01    7    Open
2020-08-01    8    Close
2020-09-01    9    Close
2020-10-01    10   Close
2020-11-01    11   Close
2020-12-01    12   Close
```

I tried someting but did not get the desired result:

```
select Date
from T1
where Date between '2020-01-12' and '2020-07-02'
and Date not in (select StartDate
from T2 where Status = 'Open')
```

**The result I want to get:**

```
Date        
------------
2020-01-12    
2020-03-18
2020-03-24
2020-06-22
2020-07-02
```

How can I get it?

Comment: Please explain the logic you want to implement.  It is not obvious.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running: MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server...?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the logic you want is:

```
select t1.date
from t1
where 
    t1.date between date '2020-01-12' and date '2020-07-02'
    and not exists (
        select 1
        from t2
        where t2.date = date_trunc('month', t1.date) and t2.status = 'Close'
    )
```

Basically this understands the dates of `t2` as starts of months, an excludes rows of `t1` whose date belongs to a "Close" month in `t2`.

You did not tell which database you are running, so this uses standard date literals and date function `date_trunc()`. The syntax may vary depending on your actual database.

The following `where` clause may be a little more efficient:

```
where t1.date >= t2.date 
  and t1.date <  t2.date + interval '1' month 
  and t2.status = 'Close'
```

Answer (score 0):

In `SQL Server`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  T1
WHERE 
EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM T2 
         WHERE T2.status  = 'OPEN' 
         AND DATEDIFF(month , T1.date, T2.StartDate)  = 0 
        )
```